# How to clarify the purpose of its use in the location modal?

Tags: ios, app-store, cllocationmanager

in my app i am showing user location on the map view So I implemented `CLLocationManager`. I got below error with Binary Rejected 
.

```
4.5 - Apps using background location services must provide a reason that clarifies the purpose of the use, using mechanisms described in the Human Interface Guidelines
```

4.5 Details

Your app uses background location services but does not clarify the purpose of its use in the location modal alert as required in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

We’ve attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

Next Steps

Please reconfigure the `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` in your code and specify the intended purpose of using background location in its message field.

Comment: When binary got reject for this reason, did u re submit the app with new build?

Comment: Yes, after adding text msg for NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in info.plist

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to write description with `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` And `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` this key in info.plist, so that user know that why your app is using gps location.
Both of the key take string as a value. and this string shows in GPS permission alert.

Add in `info.plist` as below.

[image]

Comment: yes i agree with this. but what if i ask only for while in use permission. does it still requires both ?

Comment: NO...Then you have to add just one key.

Comment: instade of adding these both keys, there is new key `Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description`